# Why doesn't Postgresql check a constrain inside a domain inside custom type inside a column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm creating the following schema:

```
create domain text_notnull as text not null;

create type foo as (
    t1 text_notnull
);

create table test (
    data foo
);

insert into test(data) values (ROW('aaa'));
/* Inserted! */

alter type foo add attribute t2 text_not_null;
/* Ok! I expected this to fail because now
   there is a row in 'test' that is violating this constrain */

insert into test(data) values (ROW('bbb'));
/* Fails, as expected */

insert into test(data) values (ROW('bbb', '2'));
/* Works, as expected */
```

If I where doing `alter table test add column x text_notnull` it would fail. Then why is adding an *invalid* attribute to a type inside a column ok, while adding it as a column is not ok?

Is there a way to force this check to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume with `alter type` - you only update the catalog. existing values are not validated. I don't think you can force it per se. but you can check bad candidates with logic, that if row has null its whole value is null. smth like:

```
select * from test where not (data) is not null
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/23WnBQWWsyReXkboTqyG48/1

also from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html

> Domain constraints, particularly NOT NULL, are checked when converting
>   a value to the domain type. It is possible for a column that is
>   nominally of the domain type to read as null despite there being such
>   a constraint.